# Need to format code for querying with exact value from combo box

Tags: ms-access

I have the following ms access query. I want it to query with the gender (female or male) selected from the combo box. At the moment, when I select "female", the query results also includes all male persons.

How should I format this code:

```
WHERE (((Q_Gender_Statistics.Year) Like [cboYear] & "*") AND ((Q_Gender_Statistics.Gender) Like "*" & [cboGender] & "*"))
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't use Like if not needed:

```
" WHERE Q_Gender_Statistics.Year = " & [cboYear] & " AND Q_Gender_Statistics.Gender = '" & [cboGender] & "'"
```

If cboGender looks up "Male/Female" form an index value, try this:

```
" WHERE Q_Gender_Statistics.Year = " & [cboYear] & " AND Q_Gender_Statistics.Gender = " & [cboGender] & ""
```

Comment: I am getting a syntax error. I've also tried: = Forms!F_Gender_Statistics!cboGender and it works, except the form now opens blank until I filter.

Comment: I added an alternative. To avoid the blank form, specify a DefaultValue for the cboGender.